# IIS 7.0 Website Fails Regularly After About 30 Minutes

Tags: iis-7, asp.net-mvc

I have a website running under IIS 7.0 on Windows Server 2008.  It's just being used by 2-3 people at any point in time under very light load.

It runs fine for about 30 minutes, but then fails with the error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Dynamic view compilation failed.
>   c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\61a09567\0ee17e160a294837a9b42f8e66a8d2c9-1.cs(6,7):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace
>   name 'MvcReCaptcha' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or
>   an assembly reference?)

MvcReCaptcha.dll is present in the bin directory, and *is certainly used* by the application while it's running (functionality provided by that DLL is referenced).

The application can be reliably restarted by:

1. Stopping that site
2. Deleting c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\61a09567
3. Restarting that site

The Application Pool is set to recycle every 1740 minutes (no other conditions).

Thoughts on what might be causing the crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is a known issue with the Spark view engine.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805779/using-asp-net-mvc-2-features-with-the-spark-view-engine

Answer (score 0):

Place the dll in the GAC, this should cause this issue to stop recurring.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Still, I would prefer not to have to GAC the DLL and would really like to understand the root cause.

Comment: Perhaps it is that IIS is misinformed as to where this resides.

Comment: How could that happen?  IIS can find the DLL initially, just seems to lose track of it at some point.  What might I have done setting up the site that could cause that behavior?